# Use Vagrant trigger to execute bash script on host

Tags: bash, vagrant, vagrant-provision, vagrant-plugin

I use Vagrant to start my testing environment. Sadly I have to retrieve information (passwords) before spinning up my Vagrant box. So far I use Vagrant-Triggers to do this and have multiple `run "do something"` commands.

**IS**

```
[:up, :provision].each do |cmd|
    config.trigger.before cmd, stdout: true do
      run "rm -rf #{cookbooks_path}"
      run "mkdir -p #{cookbooks_path}"
      run "touch fileX"
      run "touch fileY"
      run "touch fileZ"
    end
end
```

> How can I move all my commands to one batch file which I then only
>   include?

**SHOULD**

```
[:up, :provision].each do |cmd|
    config.trigger.before cmd, stdout: true do
      include_script "Vagrant_trigger_before.sh"
    end
end
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: why cant you run the script as `run "Vagrant_trigger_before.sh"`

Comment: Does this method still allow the variable substitution the 'IS' shows?

Comment: Sadly, do not know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run your script directly using the `run` instructions

```
[:up, :provision].each do |cmd|
    config.trigger.before cmd, stdout: true do
      run "Vagrant_trigger_before.sh"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

After trigger plugin was merged to vagrant mainline, the syntax seems to be changed to

```
config.trigger.before :up, :provision do |trigger|
  trigger.run = {inline: "Vagrant_trigger_before.sh"}
end
```

Ref: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/triggers/configuration#inline

Answer (score 0):

Besides this being a quite old thread, some useful hints for others who end up here:

1. As @frederic-henri and @lin-n pointed out, you can use `trigger.run` and current [trigger syntax](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/triggers) to execute a script on the host before or after specific Vagrant commands
2. [trigger.run](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/triggers/configuration#run) accepts arguments for the script

Summing up (not tested):

```
config.trigger.before :up, :provision do |trigger|
  trigger.run do |run|
    run.args = cookbooks_path
    run.path = <Script>
  end
end
```